# Git GUI - Переключение между ветками с удалением и восстановлением файлов

Tags: git, gui, git-branch

Можно, конечно, и объяснением через командную строку, но желательно через Git GUI (а иначе зачем создавать gui-клиент, который не может того, что может консоль).

Суть в том, что у разных веток разное количество файлов. И часть из файлов используется 'вручную'. В общем, мне нужно, чтобы при переключении с Ветки1 на Ветку2 удалялись файлы, не используемые Веткой2 и создавались те, что используются ей. Такое возможно?

Да, я мог бы спросить об этом у создателей программы, но здесь есть шанс на более быстрый ответ, да и, как я и сказал, меня устроит и решение через консоль.

Comment: Что означает "часть из файлов используетс вручную"?

Comment: `а иначе зачем создавать gui-клиент, который не может того, что может консоль` - не слышал ни об одном клиенте, который может всё, что может консоль. Всё-таки в консоли вы программу пишете, даже если однострочную. Но **делать всё** большинству пользователей и не нужно.

Answer (score 3):

> В общем, мне нужно, чтобы при переключении с Ветки1 на Ветку2 удалялись файлы, не используемые Веткой2 и создавались те, что используются ей.

В целом так и происходит. Давайте для начала разберёмся с терминологией, чтобы точно понимать друг друга.

**Ветка** - это всего лишь легковесный указатель на коммит. Она реализована просто как файл, а в файле лежит номер (SHA-1) коммита. Переключаясь на другую ветку вы на самом деле переключаетесь на другой коммит.

Файлы и папки не используются веткой или коммитом. Правильнее говорить, что файл (или конкретное состояние файла) *принадлежит* коммиту или *сохранено в* коммите.

Коммит внутри себя содержит структуру файлов и папок, которые в нём были сохранены, в том числе содержимое файлов. По своей сути это такая "фотография" рабочей области вашего проекта.

При переключении на другой коммит происходит перестроение всех файлов и папок на то состояние, которое сохранено в том коммите. Давайте представим, что у нас есть две ветки: `master` и `feature` и рассмотрим различные ситуации. Здесь буквы - это разные коммиты.

```
         D      feature
        /
A--B--C/--E     master*
```

Мы находимся в master и переключаемся на feature:

```
git checkout feature
```

Пусть у нас есть некоторый файл. Обозначим его содержимое в коммитах C, D, E, в рабочей области проекта (working tree, `wt`) и результат `checkout`'a (или его попытки).

- `x` - файл удалён
- `1`, `2`, `3` - различные варианты содержимого

```
|  C  |  E  |  D  |  wt | Результат
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1  |  1  |  1  |  1  | 1, без изменений
|  1  |  1  |  1  |  2  | 2, несохранённое изменение останется
|  1  |  1  |  3  |  1  | 3, терять нечего, содержимое просто меняется
|  1  |  2  |  1  |  2  | 1, аналогично
|  1  |  2  |  3  |  2  | 3, аналогично.
# итог: если последнее состояние файла закоммичено (E == wt), 
# конфликтов никогда не будет
|  1  |  1  |  2  |  3  | Fail, будет потеря несохранённых изменений
|  1  |  2  |  2  |  3  | 3, git распознаёт, что изменения в коммитах одинаковы.
|  1  |  2  |  3  |  3  | Fail. Текущее состояние файла равно сохранённому в D, 
# но с точки зрения текущего коммита это потеря несохранённых изменений. 
|  1  |  2  |  1  |  3  | Fail. Даже если файл менялся только в одном коммите,
# нельзя применить изменение "2" -> "3" к содержимому "1"

# теперь поудаляем.
|  C  |  E  |  D  |  wt | Результат
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1  |  x  |  1  |  x  | 1. Файл восстановлен, как раз то что вам нужно.
|  1  |  1  |  x  |  1  | x. В той ветке файл удалён.
|  1  |  1  |  x  |  2  | Fail, потеря изменений.
|  1  |  1  |  2  |  x  | Fail, удаление - это тоже изменение.
|  1  |  1  |  1  |  x  | x, изменение есть, но конфликта нет.

# Файл независимо появился в разных ветках
|  x  |  1  |  1  |  1  | 1, всё нормально
|  x  |  1  |  2  |  1  | 2, даже если содержимое разное
|  x  |  1  |  2  |  2  | Fail, снова потеря, хоть содержимое и совпадает.
```

Итого, результат `checkout` для каждого файла можно описать таким псевдокодом:

```
if (E == wt) {
    // Если нет несохранённых изменений, берём содержимое из D
    return D
}
else if (E == D) {
    // Если содержимое не менялось (или менялось одинаково),
    // То можно оставить текущее содержимое файла
    return wt
}
else {
    // Иначе вероятна потеря данных
    fail()
}
```

Что можно делать с несохранёнными изменениями:

1. Закоммитить
2. [Сложить в карман](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/564053/181472).
3. Отменить с помощью

   - `git reset --hard -- filename` - в одном файле
   - `git reset --hard` - отменить все изменения версионируемых (отслеживаемых) файлов
   - `git clean -f` - вообще почистить рабочую область, в том числе удалить неверсионируемые файлы. C `-fx` удалит ещё и игнорируемые файлы, с `-fd` захватит директории, а не только файлы. Вариант `-fdx` - выжигание напалмом всего, что не прибито гвоздями.

Comment: Благодарю за пояснение, учту на будущее. В моем случае оказалось достаточным перейти на SourceTree, т.к. он умеет делать то, что нужно

Comment: @user64675 пожалуйста! Самому было интересно перебрать все возможные случаи. )

Comment: @user64675 похоже, до *всех* возможных тут ещё далеко. )

Answer (score 2):

При `git checkout %branch_name%` состояние **отслеживаемых** файлов в репозитории меняется в состояние крайнего коммита этого бранча (т.е. лишние файлы скроются, а нужные - добавятся). Модифицированные и новые (не зафиксированные) файлы остаются висеть.

Чтобы очистить репозиторий от **неотслеживаемых** папок и файлов можно также выполнить `git clean -dfx`.

Comment: `git clean -dfx` аккуратно, это ещё и игнорируемые файлы удалит. Не всегда это хорошо.

Comment: @NickVolynkin верно, чтение доков никто не отменял)

Comment: Хорошая иллюстрация: https://pp.vk.me/c637328/v637328370/8e45/1-qBghDOJYw.jpg

Comment: @NickVolynkin Да ладно вам, в руках идиота и молоток - грозное оружие)

Comment: Описал пару менее разрушительных вариантов: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/564056/181472

Answer (score 2):

если файлы 'вручную' не закомичены и не лежат в индексе в ветке1, то для их сохранения необходимо положить их 'на полку до востребования' командой

`git stash save --include-untracked "имя полки"`

После этого переключиться на ветку2
Для просмотра всех стешей надо использовать

```
git stash list
```

Для извлечения файлов нужно выполнить

`git stash apply "stash@{0}"`

Нужно использовать нужный индекс

Аналогичен переход с ветки2